# svg with mask not seen on chrome

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, mask

I'm trying to mask with some svg path that is created dynamically with React. The problem is that the resulted html code doesn't render properly on Chrome and Safari immediately. Correct results appear on browser window resize or check/uncheck of a style property from inspector. I feel like the problem in one of the `-webkit` properties but can't define which. Tried `-webkit-mask`, but it didn't give any results. Here's the html structure that should render right away:

```html
<div>
  <div id="type-1-areas-container">
    <div class="drawArea" id="draw-area-type-1-area-0" style="z-index: 1;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <mask id="mask"><rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"></rect>
          <svg class="path-svg type-1-area" id="type-1-area-0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(1)" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <path id="type-1-area-0-path" class="svg-path type-1-area-path" d="M127.796875,155C132.95551452636718,162.82513122558595,138.23039932250975,168.82151107788087,142.18780517578125,172.16754150390625S150.95073318481445,176.28356399536133,154.17958068847656,177.30686950683594S161.0159019470215,179.71168899536133,163.7134552001953,178.9895782470703S169.75318450927733,178.6121047973633,172.16326904296875,172.4927978515625S179.8039924621582,147.7889892578125,179.7806854248047,138.19419860839844S175.28107757568358,115.13227272033691,172.0078887939453,108.52752685546875S164.28795928955077,96.4549690246582,157.9594268798828,94.16255950927734S134.72670631408693,93.14690742492675,129.8176727294922,93.24479675292969S128.5356559753418,90.80187454223633,125.23253631591797,94.81515502929688S107.4122241973877,110.97227325439454,107.796875,120S122.63823547363282,147.17486877441405,127.796875,155" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke: rgb(255, 255, 0); stroke-width: 2px; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: round;"></path>
          </svg>
        </mask>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="type-2-areas-container">
    <div class="drawArea" id="draw-area-type-2-area-0" style="z-index: 0;">
      <svg class="path-svg type-2-area" id="type-2-area-0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="scale(1)" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <path id="type-2-area-0-path" class="svg-path type-2-area-path" d="M114.796875,179C114.14320793151856,178.26720504760743,105.84552307128907,165.58406829833984,110.43909454345703,174.1147003173828S134.835990524292,220.88421707153321,145.42068481445312,235.87088012695312S170.70931396484374,265.35510711669923,181.00372314453125,274.0257873535156S206.31416854858398,289.6967575073242,214.05007934570312,293.6754150390625S225.51683044433594,299.6501159667969,232.5764617919922,300.5501708984375S254.67742385864258,301.13958129882815,261.1142883300781,299.67578125S271.82720336914065,295.42576599121094,275.4888916015625,290.79150390625S282.5870529174805,277.52045288085935,285.5255432128906,268.78070068359375S293.53660736083987,240.60151138305665,295.0788269042969,232.5264892578125S296.2962417602539,220.4813331604004,295.8070068359375,214.9472198486328S300.125959777832,208.6973476409912,291.8172607421875,195.6324005126953S252.8830108642578,142.17305183410645,240.41567993164062,127.84757232666016S218.41261672973633,106.83093719482422,208.70172119140625,100.12920379638672S189.46759185791015,85.5236831665039,175.67637634277344,83.16934967041016S129.72834587097168,83.31731033325195,116.76028442382812,84.43364715576172S94.4289478302002,87.4200668334961,89.2226333618164,90.6115951538086S82.60472297668457,99.19609413146972,82.05152130126953,105.71050262451172S83.84109344482422,127.42914161682128,85.53462219238281,134.04098510742188S88.95237503051757,143.0456069946289,93.34171295166016,149.78945922851562S111.57860069274902,174.61841888427733,114.796875,179S115.45054206848144,179.73279495239257,114.796875,179" style="stroke: rgb(186, 112, 0); stroke-width: 2px; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-linecap: round; fill: rgb(186, 112, 0); fill-opacity: 0.3;" mask="url(#mask)"></path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, in static mode when this HTML code is placed in codepen or jsfiddle I face no issues with render, but the problem happens when a path inside mask element is drawn dynamically with mouse. Without mask dynamically drawn paths are rendered without any issues. Already tried:

1) React `forceReload()` assuming the problem is related to the fact that the path inside mask element `<path id="type-1-area-0-path" ....></path>` appears after the path referencing mask
       `<path id="type-2-area-0-path" d="M114.796875,..." ... mask="url(#mask)"></path>`

2) Instead of inline mask attribute use CSS `mask` and `-webkit-mask` properties.

Could anyone give me a hint where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who came to this page, I have same problem and I found can fix with `mask-size` and `-webkit-mask-size`.

do this in your css:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
mask-size: cover;
-webkit-mask-size: cover;
background-color:#000;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces a similar problem here's the solution that worked for me. The problem was solved by a combination of 1) and 2) from the above problem description AND the size of the mask parent `svg` element set by viewBox, not `width` or `height` attributes or css properties (https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#article-header-id-2).

Comment: Could you include more details about this solution?

Answer (score 0):

For me it started to work when I changed mask property: maskUnits from: userSpaceOnUse to objectBoundingBox (with a plain text editor).